# Refresh user page using session Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, web

I'd like to know if I can refresh current user page from controller.
For example admin logged in. He has table with all logged in users. He clicks on a button and selected users session becomes invalid. 
The question is, how to refresh other user (not current but still logged in) page having its session.

Is there any way? Thx

Comment: How often does an admin do this?  Consider WebSockets or  perhaps long polling.

Comment: @AndrewS It's not for production) Just wondering if it's possible